# How do I use Quick Select?

Tags: terraria, keyboard

How do I use quick select using a PC in Terraria?
If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, you are able to instantly retrieve something from your inventory rather than having to go to your inventory and put something into your hot bar.  I would like to know how to better use this feature- for example, if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, how do you know which item will be instantly retrieved?

Answer (score 1):

The tool you'll be selecting when using the auto select key (default : <kbd>Shift</kbd>) will depend on the block you're pointing at, and sometimes, the condition of your character being submerged by water :

- if you point the cursor far away from your character, your character will hold the first **glowstick**, or flare gun, if available.
- air : first **torch** in your inventory

  - if you are underwater, you will hold a **waterproof torch** (cursed & ichor torch), or else a glowstick (or flare gun) (if any of them are available), but no water sensitive torches.
  - if you are outside the water but point at a pool of water, the player will hold a torch regardless of the waterproofness of the torch.
  - if you have no torch, then it's glowstick or flare gun. If you have nothing, then the auto-select will do nothing.
- block/furniture : first tool that has enough **pickaxe** power

  - pointing a block out of range will not auto-select the tool, but a light source instead.
- tree/cactus/giant glowing mushroom : first tool that has any **axe** power

  - idem for the pickaxe if the cursor is out of range.

"first" means, as 3ventic mentionned, the first fitting item, from left to right, top to bottom.
The items in the hotbar have the highest priority.

**Exception** : the hammer will never be selected with the auto-select, you have to put it in your hotbar, so you can destroy background walls or shape some blocks.

While you're holding Left mouse click with an auto-selected item, you can release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and still have the item in your hand. It will get back on your previous pick once you release the mouse click.

Comment: Minor corrections based on my experience on PC.  If your cursor is out of range of your Pickaxe or Axe, it will select a Light Source.  Out of range Light source can be either a Glowstick or Flare Gun.

Comment: Right, it doesn't only applies for pointing air. I edited that out.

Answer (score 0):

The game will select the first fitting tool (from left to right, top to bottom) to destroy the block under the cursor when you start holding shift. It will continue to have this tool selected until you let go of shift.

If there is no block under the cursor, the you will start holding a torch, or a glow stick, if your character is underwater.

If you have no fitting tool in your inventory, it will fall back to another tool or a light source.